# Install Bazel for Golang build applications in VScode

Tags: go, bazel

How to install bazel for golang application building in VScode?

Comment: your question is  broad, ask in chunks here you can check [link](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go#overview)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct support for Bazel yet, as per [`golang/go` issue 37205](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37205) ("`x/tools/gopls`: support for bazel-based projects")

[`bazelbuild/rules_go` wiki/Editor-and-tool-integration](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/wiki/Editor-and-tool-integration) has a design document for building editor and tool integration:  a new `gopackagesdriver` binary that integrates Bazel+rules_go with `golang.org/x/tools/go/packages`.
But it is not fully implemented yet (Q1 2022).

In the meantime, you can follow [Bazel IDE setup](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/wiki/Editor-setup), which involves:

- Create a launcher script, say tools/gopackagesdriver.sh:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec bazel run -- @io_bazel_rules_go//go/tools/gopackagesdriver "${@}"
```

- adding in the `.vscode/settings.json` of your workspace:

```yaml
{
  "go.goroot": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-${workspaceFolderBasename}/external/go_sdk",
  "go.toolsEnvVars": {
    "GOPACKAGESDRIVER": "${workspaceFolder}/tools/gopackagesdriver.sh"
  },
  "go.enableCodeLens": {
    "references": false,
    "runtest": false
  },
  "gopls": {
    "build.directoryFilters": [
      "-bazel-bin",
      "-bazel-out",
      "-bazel-testlogs",
      "-bazel-mypkg",
    ],
    "formatting.gofumpt": true,
    "formatting.local": "github.com/my/mypkg",
    "ui.completion.usePlaceholders": true,
    "ui.semanticTokens": true,
    "ui.codelenses": {
      "gc_details": false,
      "regenerate_cgo": false,
      "generate": false,
      "test": false,
      "tidy": false,
      "upgrade_dependency": false,
      "vendor": false
    },
  },
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
  "go.lintOnSave": "off",
  "go.vetOnSave": "off",
}
```

Comment: `"go.buildOnSave": "off",` is deprecated and is not needed when `go.useLanguageServer:true` is set.

Comment: @rams Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.